# Use "SVG polygon" hover state to fade in div right after "SVG"

Tags: html, css, svg

Is there a css only solution for this problem? I want to be able to fade in div right after SVG, but only when user hovers SVGs polygon.

The code would look something like this:

```
<svg version="1.1" id="path" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px"
viewBox="0 0 232.077 138.555" enable-background="new 0 0 232.077 138.555"
xml:space="preserve">
   <polygon fill="#FFFFFF" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="4" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="3.059,134.255
3.778,17.055 24.495,24.928 178.323,3.52 229.238,16.201 229.238,89.779 "></polygon>
</svg>

<div class="hover"></div>
```

If I would want to make this work with SVG (not svg polygon), I would write css like this:

```
svg + .hover{
  opacity:0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .3s ease;
  -moz-transition: opacity .3s ease;
  -ms-transition: opacity .3s ease;
  -o-transition: opacity .3s ease;
  transition: opacity .3s ease;
}

svg:hover + .hover{
  opacity:1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not possible with css only cause there is no selector for this. Need would be to get on hover the [parent sibling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/is-there-a-previous-sibling-css-selector) and then select the next element using the plus sign like you do in your example.

Here is JS a good choice.

Update:

```
$('svg polygon').hover( function(){
    $('.hover').css( 'opacity', 1 );
}, function(){
    $('.hover').css( 'opacity', 0 );
} );
```

This are my 5 cents to solve it.

Comment: Yeah, I think so too... I guess I'll need js after all.

Answer (score 0):

Impossible to do it with css only. It's possible using js (jquery).

Set your transition values only on `.hover {...}`, set polygon `fill="none"` and toggle `active` class with jquery.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {     
    $('polygon').hover(function(){     
        $('.hover').addClass('active');    
    },     
    function(){    
        $('.hover').removeClass('active');     
    });
});
```

```css
.hover{
  opacity:0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .3s ease;
  -moz-transition: opacity .3s ease;
  -ms-transition: opacity .3s ease;
  -o-transition: opacity .3s ease;
  transition: opacity .3s ease;
  
  
  /* remove this 2 lines */
  background: blue;
  padding: 30px;
}

.hover.active{
  opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg version="1.1" id="path" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px"
viewBox="0 0 232.077 138.555" enable-background="new 0 0 232.077 138.555"
xml:space="preserve">
   <polygon fill="none" fill-opacity="0" stroke="blue" stroke-width="4" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="3.059,134.255
3.778,17.055 24.495,24.928 178.323,3.52 229.238,16.201 229.238,89.779 "></polygon>
</svg>

<div class="hover"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's not what I asked. I want to see if there is a way to use svg's polygon tag, to affect div, what is right after svg.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is no way to do this with CSS only. This is how I solved this with jQuery

```
$( "svg polygon" )
    .mouseover(function() {
        $('.hover').fadeIn();
    }).mouseleave(function() {
        $('.hover').fadeOut();
});
```